# How to use long file description?

Tags: 7, files

Is there any easy way to store a long text description of an uploaded file?

I want to provide a long description field (textarea) when users upload files, so they can write as much as they need. Current title field is limited to 255 chars.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

---

**Edit 1**

The `file_entity` module does not support Inline Entity Form unfortunately, so this solution won't work.

Here are the related issues on Drupal.org:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2038053
https://www.drupal.org/node/2327369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Inline Entity Form pushed me in the right direction.

Here's what worked for me:

1. Install [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module. It will allow you to add fields to files, in my case a "Description" textarea field.
2. Install [File Entity Inline](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity_inline) module. It will allow you to optionally include some of the fields directly in the file upload widget.
3. Add a file field and on configuration page under "Inline fields" choose either "All available fields" or "Only selected fields".

That's it - hope this helps someone!